は vs. こそ vs. こそは in contrastive statements
I have recently learned that you can use こそ in negative statements as well, to (I assume) emphasize what is not or does not do something (as opposed to something else that is or does). What I have noticed is this usage seems to me to look similar to contrastive は, and I have even seen it used after the masu-stem of a verb like contrastive は (also as こそは in the same way).
I wish to compare these usages from this Tweet reply, which talks about how while cats do not fight to the death when they fight each other, they do tend to aim for the neck up:

そっかヤサグレ顔のブチ猫なんだ
猫は殺し合いこそはしないけど、首から上狙うものね

Considering this, how do the following three versions differ:

猫は殺し合いはしないけど、首から上狙うものね
猫は殺し合いこそしないけど、首から上狙うものね
猫は殺し合いこそはしないけど、首から上狙うものね

One more question about this usage of こそ/こそは: I noticed that in statement A marked by こそ/こそは that is followed by a "but" to create contrast, the "but" in these constructions is frequently が/けれど/けど, but is also commonly ものの as well (took up about half of the examples I could find).
Is there any reason why ものの is common with this use of こそ outside of formality?

Yes, は and こそ work similarly, and the difference between them are minor.

猫は殺し合いはしないけど

The sentence uses は, which suggests a nuance that there are many actions the cat could potentially do, and it is uncertain which of those the cat actually does or does not do.

猫は殺し合いこそしないけど
猫は殺し合いこそはしないけど

I believe these two sentences are the same meaning and nuance. The use of  こそ or こそは implies something similar to  "at least." There is a nuance that the cat does not engage in the worst action (fight to kill), but it might still engage in other negative behaviors.
To emphasize the difference between は and こそは, here are some examples.

1000円札はなくさなかったけど、 10000円札はなくした。 (correct)
1000円札こそはなくさなかったけど、 10000円札はなくした。(incorrect)

The first example is correct. It means "I didn't lost the 1000-yen bill, but the 10,000-yen bill."
The second example is incorrect because 1000円札こそはなくさなかったけど implies that losing the 1000-yen bill is the worst thing, yet you actually lost 10000-yen bill instead.
Yes, ものの is also common. It is almost the same as けど. ものの is typically used in written language, while けど is more conversational.
